# Нельзя преобразовать тип Real к Integer, хотя тип real я не вводил

Tags: pascal

Можете написать ещё про какие-либо ошибки, буду благодарен.

```
var a, c2, c3, c5, c7:integer;
begin
write('Введите число: ');
read(a);
if a > 0 then
begin
while (a mod 2 = 0) or (a mod 3 = 0) or (a mod 5 = 0) or (a mod 7 = 0) do
begin
while a mod 2 = 0 do
begin
c2 := c2 + 1;
a := a/2;
end;
while a mod 3 = 0 do
begin
c3 := c3 + 1;
a := a/3;
end;
while a mod 5 = 0 do
begin
c5 := c5 + 1;
a := a/5;
end;
while a mod 7 = 0 do
begin
c7 := c7 + 1;
a := a/7;
end;
end;
if a = 1 then
print('Сумма: ', c2 * 2 + c3 * 3 + c5 * 5 + c7 * 7)
else
print('Сумма: ', a + c2 * 2 + c3 * 3 + c5 * 5 + c7 * 7)
end
else
print('Вы ввели не натуральное число');
end.
```

Comment: Какие ошибки Вас интересуют?

Comment: Вопросы с просьбами помочь с отладкой («почему этот код не работает?») должны включать желаемое поведение, конкретную проблему или ошибку и минимальный код для её воспроизведения прямо в вопросе. Вопросы без явного описания проблемы бесполезны для остальных посетителей.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для целочисельного деления в паскале используйте `div`:

```
a := a div 5
```

Если писать `a/5` получается `Real`.